# when I click add button multiple times it should show I am here div with delete button with multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am trying to build a simple ui so that I can learn react.
- right now when I click an add button it will show I am here div and delete button
- when I click add button multiple times it should show I am here div with delete button with multiple times.
- so I research and found this example https://www.skptricks.com/2018/06/append-or-prepend-html-using-reactjs.html
- using this example I implemented the appendData method but still its not adding the div multiple times.
- in my console I am able to see how many times divs are added `console.log("this.displayData---->", this.displayData);`
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- so that in future I will fix it myself

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b2d3rb?file=demo.js

```
 onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ showResults: true });
    this.setState({ showOrHideSearch: true });
    this.displayData.push(
      <div style={{ display: this.state.showOrHideSearch ? "" : "none" }}>
        {" "}
        I am here
        <input
          ref="rbc-toolbar-label"
          type="submit"
          value="Delete"
          onClick={this.onDelete}
        />
      </div>
    );

    console.log("this.displayData---->", this.displayData);

    this.setState({ showdata: this.displayData });
  };
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a list of `I am here` with the button?

Comment: Do not push HTML into your state like that. Instead, create a component that uses the data from the state to render your data with a delete button. More information here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: @BugHunterUK hey I created a new component , but not sure how to  use the data from the state to render your data with a delete button. Can you update in my sandbox its so confusing :( https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b2d3rb?file=newComponent.js

Comment: @Miroslav yes :(

Comment: @zizi hey, you should take a look at https://codepen.io/marekdano/pen/bVNYpq, it will give you a good understanding on how to create a to-do style application. Here is another good example https://codepen.io/Tiendq/pen/jrZAWk. These demonstrate how you can update your state and when to.  

One reason why you are not receiving a list of `I am here` rows is because you only ever render one. Also, page reloads due to the `submit`. 

Hope this helps! cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is you should not use this.setState multiple times,  instead you should do them in one line. And instead of pushing data into class variables,  you should set that data into your state variable and the same variable you should use in your render function. It will be good if you can share your complete code..

Comment: Please check my below answer(code sample) if this is still pending at your end...

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Calendar from 'rc-calendar';
import DatePicker from 'rc-calendar/lib/Picker';
import 'rc-calendar/assets/index.css';
import moment from 'moment';

class CalendarPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("AsyncValidationForm  this.props---->", this.props);

    this.state = {
      displayData: []
    };
  }

  onClick = () => {
    let displayData = [...this.state.displayData];

    displayData.push( { text: 'I am here' });
    this.setState({ displayData: displayData });
  };

  onDelete = index => {
    let displayData = [...this.state.displayData];
    if(index > -1){
      displayData.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.setState({ displayData: displayData });
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState(
      {
        [name]: value,
        pristine: false
      },
      () => {
        this.props.handleChange(name, value); //setState username, password of VerticalLinearStepper.js
      }
    );
  };

   onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var newItemValue = this.refs.itemName.value;

    if(newItemValue) {
      this.props.addItem({newItemValue});
      this.refs.form.reset();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;
    let { displayData} = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="add" onClick={this.onClick} />
          {displayData.length  > 0 ? displayData.map(function(data, index) {
            return (
            <div key={index}>
              {data.text} - For testing added index on screen {index}
              <input
                ref="rbc-toolbar-label"
                type="submit"
                value="Delete"
                onClick={() => this.onDelete(index)}
              />
            </div>
          )}, this) : null}
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default CalendarPage;
```